# Is there a optimal batch size for arc4random_buf?

Tags: c, macos, performance, random, arc4random

I need billions of random bytes from `arc4random_buf`, and my strategy is to request X random bytes at a time, and repeat this many times.

My question is how large should X be. Since the `nbytes` argument to `arc4random_buf` can be arbitrarily large, I suppose there must be some kind of internal loop that generates some entropy each time its body is executed. Say, if X is a multiple of the number of random bytes generated each iteration, the performance can be improved because I’m not wasting any entropy.

I’m on macOS, which is unfortunately closed-source, so I cannot simply read the source code. Is there any portable way to determine the optimal X?

Comment: Sounds like benchmarking would be your best bet.

Comment: @pjs A little off-topic, but I’ve just read your profile, and think you might be able to provide some great insight to [my question on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/396303/108877)?

Comment: Large parts of macOS are, in fact, open source. The `arc4random_buf()` implementation is [here](https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1272.200.26/gen/FreeBSD/arc4random.c.auto.html).

Comment: @pjs it is! Initially I was expecting a quick answer like “CSPRNGs are good for Monte Carlo simulations”, but reading these papers would definitely teach me a lot. Also thanks for your link!

Answer (score 2):

Doing some benchmarks on typical target systems is probably the best way to figure this out, but looking at a couple of implementations, it seems unlikely that the buffer size will make much difference to the cost of `arc4random_buffer`.

The original implementation implements `arc4random_buffer` as a simple loop around a function which generates one byte. As long as the buffer is big enough to avoid excessive call overhead, it should make little difference.

The FreeBSD library implementation appears to attempt to optimise by periodically computing about 1K of random bytes. Then `arc4random_buffer` uses `memcpy` to copy the bytes from the internal buffer to the user buffer.

For the FreeBSD implementation, the optimal buffer size would be the amount of data available in the internal buffer, because that minimizes the number of calls to `memcpy`.  However,  there's no way to know how much that is, and it will not be the same on every call because of the rekeying algorithm.

My guess is that you will find very little difference between buffer sizes greater than, say, 16K, and probably even less. For the FreeBSD implementation, it will be very slightly more efficient if your buffer size is a multiple of 8.

---

Addendum: All the implementations I know of have a global rekey threshold, so you cannot influence the cost of rekeying by changing the buffer size in `arc4random_buffer`. The library simply rekeys every X bytes generated.